# Can I cut out a 12" section of a footing to run new plumbing in a basement?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, basement, cutting, footings

I am finishing my basement and need to run plumbing to the planned bathroom. To do so, I need to cut out a 12" section of a footing (can't go under it). The section in question is under a door opening. Can this type of footing be cut into and removed?

Comment: *a* footing (for a pillar), no. A useless (? ... what about lateral forces on the foundation?) section of *the* footing ... IDK, +1

Comment: How does the existing drain exit the house?

Comment: "Can't" , or "Don't want to do the work involved" ?   doing it the right way is always better

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you may want to check with your local building official for local requirements.

The normal way to do this is to **core drill** through the wall/footing and insert a **protective sleeve two standard pipe-sizes bigger than the drain.**  For a 3" bathroom drain that calls for a 6" nominal Sch40 pipe which has a 6-5/8" outer diameter.  That's a big job and you may want to rent a core drilling rig for it or hire somebody to come do it.

You could also use a rotary hammer; in fact, you may need one anyway if you have to chip around rebar to cut it out.

*Why is your sewer line not low enough to go underneath your footing?*  That seems unlucky.  If the sewer line isn't very long it might be easier to replace it.  Try to find out how deep your city connection is and whether re-laying it would be an alternative before cutting through your footing!

Comment: Digging under the footing would severely undermine the footing. If you dig under the footing, expect significant settlement.

Comment: @LeeSam  Not if done right , i.e.  properly backfilling with poured concrete or equivalent

Comment: @CarlWitthoft How are you going to tie cut rebar back into footing?

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I dug under the footing, and there may be barely enough space to have the correct slope.

Comment: I dug under the footing, but only a section that is 12" inches wide. The footing is ~70 feet wide.

Comment: If you can go under, it will sure be easier than going through!  If you can, install a clean-out riser near where you're going under the footing (inside or outside.)  That way, if there is ever a problem with not enough slope on the line, you will be able to diagnose it easily and maybe mitigate it without any new digging / cutting.

Comment: @Lee Sam - Footers I've seen don't have any rebar in them.  They are just a slab of poured concrete, of the appropriate dimension.  Then the concrete block wall is built on top of it.